# TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, next.js, babel-loader

I am getting the following error in my project:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-babel-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined`
Here is my next.config.json
`module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(less)/,
        loader: 'emit-file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'dist/[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'raw-loader' },
          { loader: 'less-loader', options: { javascriptEnabled: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: [
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }
    );
    return config;
  }
};
```

And my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["inline-import", { "extensions": [".css"] }],
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd" }]
  ],
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "ignore": []
}
```

I figured the problem comes up when importing packages:
If i import packages in this manner it works:
import module from package
However, if I import the packages in this manner, I get the error described:
import module from package/submodule
Why is this happening? I suspect that the problem is with babel-loader but I don't have a clue on how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to load `.less` files?

Comment: No, I loaded `.less` files successfully. The problem is when I try to import modules from directories within the package. Could it be a problem with babel-plugin-import?

Comment: can you please show me an example of "import modules from directories within the package"?

Comment: `import IntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input';` // this works when I only add this
// but it stops working when I import modules like this
`import 'file-loader?name=libphonenumber.js!./libphonenumber.js';`
`import './main.css';`

Comment: what is libphonenumber.js? is it some npm module?

Comment: It is a phone number parsing and formatting library by Google. https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js

Comment: `import { parseNumber, formatNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js';` works fine. I might be missing something from your question but I dont really see any issues.

Comment: Did you try it on your dev machine?

Comment: yes. Will add code snippet to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the setup that works for me

**/next.config.js**

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
module.exports = withLess();
```

See this [docs on how to enable CSS Modules](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-less#with-css-modules)

**/pages/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { parseNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js';
import '../styles.less';

export default () => {
  const info = parseNumber('Phone: +1 (800) 555 35 35.', 'US');

  return (
    <h1 className="example">
      Phone info: {info.country} | {info.phone}
    </h1>
  );
};
```

**/styles.less**

```
@font-size: 50px;

.example {
  font-size: @font-size;
  color: red;
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
  "less": "^3.8.1",
  "libphonenumber-js": "^1.5.1",
  "next": "^7.0.1",
  "react": "^16.5.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
}
```

I do not have `.babelrc` file at all.

Comment: I was looking for this like hell man! I was facing issue while importing css file from dist. Thanks you are my savior!